# Camel JMS Cache Producer Connection

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, jms, ibm-mq

I am using Camel to put a message onto an IBM MQ queue. I need this producer connection to stay open once established. When I send a message, it appears to connect and disconnect for each message sent. I know there is a setting for cacheLevelName, but this appears to only be used for the consumer side. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: what makes you think it disconnects the MQ side ?

Comment: You can configure settings on the JMS connection factory, which essentially can cache connections. For example spring has a connection pool that can do this.

Comment: @AxelPodehl Thanks for asking this - I was actually checking IPPROCS on the IBM MQ Queue. I always assumed that was active connections, but it is actually "Open input connections." I should have been checking OPPROCS. I am already using spring connection pooling, so everything seems to be working as expected. Thanks!

Comment: @ClausIbsen Related topic - my goal is to shave off processing time of the first message sent by creating the producer connection on startup. I know this is the default behavior for JMS consumers, but there doesn't seem to be configurable behavior for producer side? I would assume that testConnectionOnStartup would achieve this, but the connection is not added to the pool when this is used. I've been digging around the code looking for something I can call to manually start a connection without sending a message, but have had no luck. Any ideas?